# how do i protect/lock the files of a font I designed?

Tags: typesetting, font-design

how do i protect my font design for reselling on-line on font sites? 
Is a license good enough, i want to sell allowing others to use in designs/logos etc.
Can I lock the "Affinity Designer" files of a font I designed?

Comment: What Affinity Designer files? When selling fonts you'd normally just be selling font files (e.g. TTF and/or OTF files)

Comment: regarding to lock/protect: just noticed a few font designers have a 3 EPS file option for buyers to purchase & download as well as TTF/OTF?

Comment: I'm designing a vector font in Affinity Design, then will transfer into a Font software.  After font family is complete with Alfa & punctuations...

Answer (score 3):

A license is the only thing that ever protects you in digital media sales. Simply because if you want your client to use something he has to be able to access that something. No, DRM can not even technically work. All it can do is make the opportunity cost slightly lower.

All known, and practical, digital countermeasures can be circumvented. The license is all that there is. If you want to make money that's your only realistic option.